# Filtering a dataframe in a loop and apply a function or applying a function on each element of a dataframe (?)

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement, lapply

I am struggling to perform the following task I have a data frame with 5 columns.

```
> df  
        id     c month  n             s
1    10076 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
2    10233 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
3    15590 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
4    20373 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
5    21161 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
6    22057 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
7    22929 Other     1  1 Other_Breeder
```

The third column codes for the Month (possible values 1 to 12) of the sample. I have repeated records for each month

For each month, taking the n value I would like to apply the following function

```
1-(1-s[i]*a[i])^df$n[i]
```

where s and a are vectors, results of a simulation (10000 iterations) I gave it a try with a for loop

```
results<-data.frame(m1=numeric(iters))
results<-cbind(results,rep(results[1],11))
colnames(results)<-paste("m", sep = "_", 1:12)



for (j in seq_along(results)) {
  for (i in 1:iters) {
    if (df$month[i]== "1"){results$m_1[i]<-1-(1-s[i]*a[i])^df$n[i]}
    if (df$month[i]== "2"){results$m_2[i]<-1-(1-s[i]*a[i])^df$n[i]}
    ########etc
  } 
}
but it returns 0 values . I also tried to split the dataframe and apply a function over the list

df=split(df,df$month)
results=lapply(df,function(x)1-(1-s*p)^df[[x]]$n)
```

but I didn't make a go for it.

Could anyone help me to code it properly?

I would like to obtain a vector of length= iters for each month e.g.

```
m1=df %>% filter (month=="1") 
m1new<-numeric(iters) 
for (i in 1:iters) { m1new[i]<- 1 - (1 - s[i] * a[i])^m1$n[i]}
```

this should be repeated for each month and the output should be stored in a list (12 elements) or dataframe with 12 columns

Thanks !!!

Comment: Why not just `df$newly_calculated <- 1 - (1 - s * a)^df$n`, if the lengths of s, a and the month column of your df are the same, as your question suggests? If not, please share an example of how your vectors s and a, and the desired result should look like.

Comment: I would like to obtain a vector of length= iters for each month e.g. m1=df %>% filter (month=="1") m1new<-numeric(iters) for (i in 1:iters) { m1new[i]<- 1 - (1 - s[i] * a[i])^m1$n[i]} this should be repeated for each month and can be stored in a list or dataframe with 12 columns

Comment: @I_O  any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: `list_result=list();`
`for (i in 1:12){`
`dfsub=df[,which(df$month==i)];`
`list_result=c(list_result,list(1 - (1 - s * a)^dfsub$n))`
`}`
Your example is quite a bit difficult to reproduce/understand. The idea here is just to loop up the above answer over the 12 month and store it in a list. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Smich7 hi ! thanks but the code you are proposing doesn't work .. I got vectors with 0 as items within the list

Comment: @Smich7 if I use the for loop as in my example .. only the first column (m1) is properly filled with values ... the remaining columns have a lot of 0s

Comment: I've put a wrong coma, just edited my above message:
list_result=list(); 
for (i in 1:12){ 
dfsub=df[which(df$month==i),]; list_result=c(list_result,list(1 - (1 - s * a)^dfsub$n)) 
}

Comment: @Smich7 .. I have still problem .. "Error in df[which(sero.data$Month == i), ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" .. to solve it I converted "Month" into a factor but another issue arose "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".  Do you know what the problem is ? Why did you not include a nested loop with 1:iters ? thanks a lot for you help !!!!

Comment: @Smich7 I am creating a new post with the reprex output so that it will be easier to understand and reproduce .. could you have a look at it ?

Comment: @Smich7 here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096880/loop-over-months-with-different-records-per-month